# Python:keep only matched items and leave rest of items in list

Tags: python-2.7

> [{"timestamp": 1495126913.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55",
>   "remote_host": "78.47.139.58"}, {"timestamp": 1495126913.0,
>   "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"},
>   {"timestamp": 1495126913.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host":
>   "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp": 1495126915.0, "client_ip":
>   "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp":
>   1495126915.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp": 1495126915.0, "client_ip":
>   "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "78.47.139.58"}, {"timestamp":
>   1495126915.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"}, {"timestamp": 1495126917.0, "client_ip":
>   "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp":
>   1495126917.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"}, {"timestamp": 1495126917.0, "client_ip":
>   "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"}]

In Python, find all entries which matches with remote_host = `78.47.139.58` . Show all but only matched one and save into list.
For eg:

**Expected answer**

> [{"timestamp": 1495126913.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55",
>   "remote_host": "78.47.139.58"},{"timestamp": 1495126915.0,
>   "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "78.47.139.58"}]

Comment: What's the actual question ?

Please read this to understand how to write a good question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by

```
list_arr= [{"timestamp": 1495126913.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "78.47.139.58"}, {"timestamp": 1495126913.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"}, {"timestamp": 1495126913.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp": 1495126915.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp": 1495126915.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp": 1495126915.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "78.47.139.58"}, {"timestamp": 1495126915.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"}, {"timestamp": 1495126917.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "175.106.59.78"}, {"timestamp": 1495126917.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"}, {"timestamp": 1495126917.0, "client_ip": "10.200.3.55", "remote_host": "201.83.41.11"}]
filtered = [_ for _ in list_arr if _['remote_host'] == '78.47.139.58']
print(filtered)
```

**UPDATED**

Another approach is to use the `lambda` method

```
filt = list(filter(lambda x: x['remote_host'] == '78.47.139.58', list_arr))
print(filt)
```

Sample Demo link https://repl.it/HSRf/4